how to text non apple users on my MacBook Air?
I have pure talk & so do my parents for some reason im not able to text them from my MacBook they have android phones im able to text anyone who has iPhones/iMessage but not sms? can anyone help me?

Can you text them from your phone?

Set up iPhone to get SMS messages on Mac
You can set up your iPhone so that you can receive and send SMS messages (short text messages) and MMS messages (text messages with graphics, audio, video, and other media) on your Mac. After you set up your iPhone, when you receive an SMS message, it appears on both your iPhone and your Mac. When you send a message to someone who uses a phone other than an iPhone, your message is sent as an SMS message.
https://support.apple.com/guide/messages/get-sms-texts-from-iphone-on-your-mac-icht8a28bb9a/mac
